# Finding the position of an element from another

Tags: javascript, testing

I would like to click on an element (without id) thanks to the coordinates of another (found with his id).

I am thinking of something like

```
.click(apple + offsetX)
.click(orange + offsetX)
```

I hope it's clear I am new to Javascript and testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not soclear but I think you want something just like this.
for apple element. calculate x position and y position of apple element and run this code;

```
var x = /*calculate x position of apple*/;
var y = /*calculate y position of apple*/;

document.elementFromPoint(x,y).click();
```

there is an example for you

https://codepen.io/lumosmind/pen/PoPGwZZ